# Exporting large number to csv from R

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I came across a strange problem when trying to export an R dataframe to a csv file. 
The dataframe contains some big numbers, but when they are written to the csv file, they "lose" the decimal part and are instead written without it. 
But not like one would expect, but like this:

Say 3224571816.5649 is the correct value in R. When written to csv, it becomes 32245718165649.

I am using the `write.csv2` function to write the csv. The separators are correct, as it works normally for smaller values. Is the problem occurring because the number (with decimals) is bigger than 32bit?

And more importantly, how can I solve this, as I have a whole dataframe with values as big (or bigger) than this? Also, it has to be written in to a csv.

Comment: Can´t you convert the dataframe content to text/characters before printing?

Comment: It works for me with the number you supplied. doesn't this have something to do with `max.print` option? What is your value of `options('max.print')` ?

Comment: Also have you tried other write methods (e.g. `fwrite()` from `data.table`) ?

Comment: @Oka When I read your comment, I checked the column types. And apparently R already transformed them to characters. And this is what is causing the problems (and why JaKu has no problems with this number). The problems are caused by the fact that $.$ is not transformed to $,$ as R thinks they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

write.csv2 is intended for a different standard of csv (Western European styling, which based on your use of a "." as a decimal indicator, I am guessing you are not looking for). write.csv2 uses a comma as a decimal indicator and a semicolon as the field delimiter, so if you are trying to read the result in as a comma separated file, it will look strange indeed.

I suggest you use write.csv (or even better, write.table) to output your file. write.csv assumes a comma separator and period for decimal marker.

both write.csv and write.csv2 are just wrappers for write.table, which is the underlying method. In general, I recommend use of write.table because it does not assume your region and you can explicitly pass it sep = ",", dec = ".", etc. This not only lets you know what you are using for sure, but it also makes your code a lot more readable.

for more, check the rdocumentation.org site for write.table: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.3/topics/write.table

Comment: I think my comment was misunderstood. I am using the correct styling (Westeren European), but because the numbers are (apparently) too big, R transforms them from numeric to character. And because R uses a decimal point, the new strings have "." as a decimal indicator, which then causes problems, as "," is expected by my system. So I have to manually change the strings of numbers (or manually tranform them into numeric again).

Comment: Interesting! It sounds like the answer is immediately in front of you: cast that column to string yourself before wrting it to csv and you won't get your "," replaced with a "."