# decimal sign disappears when exporting data frame from R to .csv

Tags: r, csv, class, export, decimal-point

I am exporting an R data frame to .csv using Rstudio. All numbers are between 0 and 1, but when I open the .csv some of them "lost" their decimal separators (.) . The effect is that those numbers are now in the hundrets instead of between 0 and 1.
The pattern I can make out is that this only happens to numbers with three digits behind the dot.
E.g.
0.60300 appears in the .csv as 603 whereas
0.59000 and 0.69780 stay the same.

The only similar question I found so far is this: [exporting-large-number-to-csv-from-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299050/exporting-large-number-to-csv-from-r)
There it seems like it had to do with the numbers' classes so I played around a bit with a test data frame and found out, that the issue is the same, if the values are classified as numbers but not if they are factors.
Does anybody have an idea, why 0.xxx00 numerics are not correctly exportet?
Since I get the data frame in numerics, I could obviously write a line to transform my data frame to factors before exporting it but I feel like this should not be necessary!? Also the code I am sing has worked before so either the problem didn't exist then or the former calculations are incorrect (unlikely).

Here is what I used to test the issue:
(I am quite sure, this can be done much more properly but as a newbie this is what I could come up with :-) )

```
> Technology <- c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")  
> Score <- c("0.1234", "0.1230", "0.3321", "0.9800", "0.7880")  
> Appropriateness <- c("0.7887", "0.5480", "0.5590", "0.1780", "0.8400")  
> Test<- c("0.1234567", "0.2000", "0.543311123", "0.222222", "0.5436939003")  
> df<-data.frame(Technology, Score, Appropriateness, Test)

> sapply(df, class)  
     Technology Score Appropriateness Test   
     "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" 

> write.table(df, file = "demo/TestDataframeI.csv")

> df$Score<- as.numeric(as.character(df$Score))  
> df$Appropriateness<- as.numeric(as.character(df$Appropriateness))  
> df$Test<- as.numeric(as.character(df$Test))

> sapply(df, class)  
    Technology Score Appropriateness Test 
    "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 

> write.table(df, file = "demo/TestDataframeII.csv")
```

Looking forward to your input!

Comment: Are you sure they are not exported correctly? Have you opened the file with a plain text editor (like Notepad)? I suspect you open the file with Excel and "," is the decimal separator in Excel (i.e., European format). If that's the case, either specify this decimal separator in `write.table` or change it to "." in Excel or specify it during Excel import.

Comment: Try use `write.csv` instead of `write.table`. Also, if that doesn't work, perhaps specify the encoding (I.e., `encoding="UTF-8"`).

Comment: Study `help("write.table")`.

Comment: @Roland, you are right, in an editor the numbers are displayed correctly, so they are exported correctly.
It must have to do with the separation in libreoffice but it's not a comma issue. (I had checked that :-) ) 
But why does this influence further calculations with the .csv RStudio?

@QAsena, Appartenly the command ```write.table``` uses a space to separate columns by default!?